# How optimize code to copy one sheet range to another sheet range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My code below works, but I thinking that there's a much more elegant way of doing it.  I want to copy a portion of a selected row (D:R) on the Customer sheet (source) to the Test sheet (destination) to the first blank row in that sheet (C:Q).

The code works, but just looks non-performant/non-elegant.

```
function rowSelected() {  
  var customer_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Customer_Info");
  var invoice_sheet =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var customer_selection_row = customer_sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  //Browser.msgBox(customer_selection_row);

  var customer_selection_start = 'D' + customer_selection_row;
  var customer_selection_end = 'R' + customer_selection_row;
  var customer_selection_range = customer_selection_start + ':' + customer_selection_end;
  var source_range = customer_sheet.getRange(customer_selection_range);
  customer_sheet.setActiveRange(source_range);
  //Browser.msgBox(source_range.getA1Notation());

  var invoice_selection_row = getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow();
  var invoice_selection_start = 'C' + invoice_selection_row;
  var invoice_selection_end = 'Q' + invoice_selection_row;
  var invoice_selection_range = invoice_selection_start + ':' + invoice_selection_end;
  var destination_range = invoice_sheet.getRange(invoice_selection_range);
  invoice_sheet.setActiveRange(destination_range);
  //Browser.msgBox(destination_range.getA1Notation());

  customer_sheet.setActiveRange(source_range).copyTo((destination_range), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

I'm thinking there is some way of doing this with less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to copy the column "D" to "R" at the row of the active range of the sheet `Customer_Info` to the column "C" to "Q" at the row retrieved by `getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()` of the sheet `Test`.
- You want to activate the source range.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is declared one time as `ss``.
- `getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)` is used instead of `getRange(a1Notation)`.
- About `destination_range`, when the start cell is set, the source range can be copied from it.
- When the active sheet is `Customer_Info`, the script is run.

#### Modified script:

```
function rowSelected() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var customer_sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if (customer_sheet.getSheetName() == "Customer_Info") {
    var invoice_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
    var activeRange = ss.getActiveRange();
    var source_range = customer_sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(), 4, activeRange.getNumRows(), 15).activate();
    var destination_range = invoice_sheet.getRange(getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow(), 3); // or invoice_sheet.getRange("C" + getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow())
    source_range.copyTo(destination_range, {contentsOnly: true});
  }
}
```

- `getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()` of your script is also used for above modified script.
- In this modified script, if you want to select the range of "A1:A3" on the sheet `Customer_Info` and run the script, the values of cells "D1:R3" are copied from the cell of the column "C" and the row of `getFirstEmptyRowWholeRow()`.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
- [activate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#activate())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for this input, I will test it.

Comment: @Alan W. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.